# Configuring Squid proxy server

Tags: proxy, mac, squid, access-control-list

I have installed squid on a mac mini and would like to configure it to be used as a proxy

Any ideas where i would start, especially setting up the ACLs, am using webmin as the GUI tool for configuring squid

Answer (score 1):

http://gadmintools.flippedweb.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=47&Itemid=37

nothing better and this !!!for squid GUI

Comment: up-point for pointing out that Redhat has a GUI admin for Squid.  will Redhat work "out of the box" with this admin tool or is it tough to get the admin tool configured?

Comment: Hi I didnt got you are asking. This tool work on the same server where you install squid not remote setup is it what your looking

Answer (score 0):

Alright - if you are not using your mac mini as your gateway for all internet traffic, and if you don't have a really good reason to cache/log traffic, uninstall Squid, stop reading now.

Configuring Squid is *not* trivial - in fact, there is a book that was written about configuring it. That's how much goes into it.
But, by all means, read this:
http://www.linuxjunkies.org/adminstration%20Howto/webminguide/c4380.htm

.. And good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the webmin docs to be very helpful.

http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SquidProxyServer